# Trace Dependents for cells used in charts

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

How can we use **VBA, to determine if a particular Excel cell is used in a chart** elsewhere in the Workbook?

I regularly use the built-in Trace Dependents function to see how readily I can change/remove cells, but it only indicates which *cell functions* refer to the cell.

(There's a related old, unanswered question at [Mr. Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/trace-dependents-for-cells-used-in-charts.919115/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, as far as I know, nothing build-in, you will need to use some VBA code.
You will need to understand the object model of a chart in Excel/VBA:

A worksheet has a collection of `DataSheetObjects`.
A `DataSheetObject` is the container for the chart itself, stored as propery `Chart`.
The chart contains a collection of data series. The visible series can be accessed with `SeriesCollection`, all (even the hidden) series with `FullSeriesCollection`.

Unfortunately, it is a little bit tricky to access the range that is used in a series. You have to use the property `Formula`, that looks something like this: `=SERIES("MyName",Sheet1!$A$4:$A$7,Sheet1!$B$4:$B$7,1)`.

Lets quickly look at the pieces: It contains basically 4 pieces, separated with a comma:
(0) the series name: `"MyName"` (With the Prefix `=SERIES(`, but we don't care).
(1) the range holding the x-axis values: `Sheet1!$A$4:$A$7`
(2) the range holding the values: `Sheet1!$B$4:$B$7,1`
(3) the index: `1` (plus the closing `)` )

We are interested in the two ranges. So what we have to do is to write a functiont that extract this ranges and compare it with the cell you are interested in. The following function checks this for *one* chart:

```
Function isCellUsedInChart(cell As Range, ch As Chart) As Boolean
    Dim s As Series
    For Each s In ch.FullSeriesCollection
        ' Debug.Print s.Formula
        Dim pieces() As String
        pieces = Split(s.Formula, ",")
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 2
            Dim p As Long, sheetname As String, seriesAdr As String, seriesRange As Range
            p = InStr(pieces(i), "!")
            ' Extract sheetname
            sheetname = Left(pieces(i), p - 1)
            If sheetname <> cell.Parent.Name Then Exit Function     ' different sheet.
            
            ' Extract data range
            seriesAdr = Mid(pieces(i), p + 1)
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = cell.Parent
            Set seriesRange = ws.Range(seriesAdr)
            
            If Not Intersect(seriesRange, cell) Is Nothing Then
                isCellUsedInChart = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    Next s
End Function
```

Now all you have to do is to loop over all charts of all sheets, or with other words, of all ChartObjects of all Worksheets.

A small addition: You might have charts as a sheet in a workbook. You can access them using the `Charts`-collection of the workbook. For this, the 2nd loop in the following function is used.

```
Function isCellUsedInAnyChart(cell As Range) As Boolean

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, co As ChartObject
    Set wb = cell.Parent.Parent
    ' Loop over all worksheets
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each co In ws.ChartObjects
            If isCellUsedInChart(cell, co.Chart) Then
                isCellUsedInAnyChart = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Dim ch As Chart
    ' Loop over all chart sheets
    For Each ch In wb.Charts
         If isCellUsedInChart(cell, ch) Then
            isCellUsedInAnyChart = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Top!
Some small issues:
1. Series Name, i.e. "MyName" in the example, can be a reference
2. x-Values may well be no data series (leading to an empty 'pieces' element)

To cope with these, I added 3 things
a) starting from 0 with i: `For i = 0 To 2`,
b) remove =SERIES( from the first piece, e.g. `pieces(0) = Replace(pieces(0), "=SERIES(", "")`
c) Starting from `If sheetname <> [...]`, wrap the rest of the `i`-loop body into a `If p > 0 Then` condition

Comment: Finally, in some of my objects it loops through, s.Formula seems to lead to an error (no clue which of my tonds of objects it is, sadly); I improvised a try-catch type wrapping around the `pieces = Split(s.Formula, ",")` statement, allowing to flag it. Then it works for me so far: Seems to detect the cells used for graph data & series names.

Comment: Axis names and Title are, afaik, not detected for now; addressing these would be a useful extension.

Comment: FWIW: In my case, some situations where the **script didn't detect** that a chart is using a cell's data (I have not yet checked to which degree this is systematic/the real reasons): **1. Waterfall chart; 2. Chart on sheet with space in sheetname**.